# Creating wrapper component for react-router-dom v6 Route that logs route changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-component

We are looking to add custom logging to our react application, and would like to log each time a user changes routes. To handle this, we are creating a wrapper component , and this is what we currently have:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function LoggerRoute(isExact, path, element) {
    useEffect(() => {
        // send route-change log event to our mongodb collection
    }, []);

    // And return Route
    return (
        isExact
            ? <Route exact path={path} element={element} />
            : <Route exact path={path} element={element} />
    );
}

export default LoggerRoute;
```

...and in our App.js file, we have changed the routes as such:

```
// remove this // <Route exact path='/tools/team-scatter' element={<TeamScatterApp />} />
<LoggerRoute isExact={true} path='/tools/team-scatter' element={<TeamScatterApp />} />
```

However, this throws the error `Uncaught Error: [LoggerRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`.

Additionally, it feels off passing props to a route, if possible we would prefer

```
<LoggerRoute exact path='/tools/team-scatter' element={<TeamScatterApp />} />
```

as the ideal way to call our LoggerRoute. We like the idea of a wrapper component, this way we don’t have to add logging into every component that our app routes to. However, I’m not sure if this wrapper component approach is possible if  can only accept a  component. How can we modify our `LoggerRoute` component to work / be better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` only `Route` and `React.Fragment` are valid children of the `Routes` component. Create either a wrapper component or a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) component to handle listening for route path changes. Since you presumably want to do this for more than one route at-a-time I suggest the layout route method, but you can create a component that handles either.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const RouteListenerLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    // send route-change log event to our mongodb collection
  }, [pathname]);

  return children ?? <Outlet />;
};
```

The `children` prop is used in the cases where you want to wrap individual routed components (*i.e. the `element` prop*) **or** an entire component, (*i.e. `App`) that is rendering a set of `Routes`. The `Outlet` component is used in the case where you want to conditionally include a subset of routes within a `Routes` component (*i.e. some nested `Route` components*).

Wrap the routes you want to listen to route changes for.

Examples:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<RouteListenerLayout />}>
    <Route path="path1" element={<SomeComponent />} />
    <Route path="someOtherPath" element={<SomeOtherComponent />} />
    ... wrapped routes components with listener
  </Route>
  ... routes w/o listener
</Routes>
```

or

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={(
      <RouteListenerLayout>
        <SomeComponent />
      </RouteListenerLayout>
    )}
  />
</Routes>
```

or

```
<RouteListenerLayout>
  <App />
</RouteListenerLayout>
```

These all assume the router is rendered higher in the ReactTree than `RouteListenerLayout` so the `useLocation` hook works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In v6, `<Route>` is a lot more strict than it was in v5. Instead of building wrappers for , it may be used only inside other `<Routes>` or `<Route>` elements. If you try to wrap a `<Route>` in another component it will never render.

What you should be doing instead is adding a wrapper component and leveraging it in the `element` prop on the route.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/public" element={<PublicPage />} />
      <Route
        path="/route"
        element={
          <AddLogging>
            <YourPage/>
          </AddLogging>
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Edit: here is an example wrapper component based on your needs:

```
function AddLogging({children}) {
    useEffect(() => {
        // send route-change log event to our mongodb collection
        // can use useLocation hook to get route to log
    }, []);

    return children;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `RouterProvider` by doing two things

- creating extended route object (RouteObject with my own props)
- mapping them

  - by adding wrapper with protection and custom logic
  - filtering back from ExtendedRouteObject to RouteObject

Use code below or [npm-package](https://react-router-dom-wrapping) based on snippet below

```
// Overwrite is my custom type in order to override any type i need
type TExtendedRouteObject = Overwrite<
  RouteObject,
  {
    children?: TExtendedRouteObject[];
  }
> & {
  /**
   * In order to set to document.title
   */
  title: string;
};

const mapExtendedRoutes = (routeObjects: TExtendedRouteObject[]): RouteObject[] => {
  if (routeObjects.length) {
    return routeObjects.map(route => {
      if (route.children?.length) {
        return omit({
          ...route,
          element: <RouteWrapper {...route} />,
          children: mapExtendedRoutes(route.children),
        },
        ['title'],
      ) as RouteObject;
      }

      return omit({ // omit from lodash.omit
        ...route,
        element: <RouteWrapper {...route} />,
      }) as RouteObject;
    });
  }

  return [];
};

const RouteWrapper: FC<TExtendedRouteObject> = ({ element, title }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = title;
  }, [title]);

  // your logger logic goes here

  return <>{element}</>;
};

const extendedRoutes: TExtendedRouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    title: 'Homepage',
    element: <Dashboard />,
    children: [...],
  },
...
];

const routes: RouteObject[] = mapExtendedRoutes(extendedRoutes);

const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);
// then pass it to <RouterProvider router={router} />
```